# About event addition method of Angular ui-calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events, calendar

Please tell me addition method of event with angular ui calendar.
Now's $scope.events.push, (,), using event is being added, but when changing the month, all added event is reset.

If someone is using angular ui-calendar and goes to a event addition, please instruct in the way.

※ Formal demonstration, like, I think that I get up. 
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/
* Procedure
1. "Add Event" on the screen left side is clicked. An event "Open Sesame" is added on November 28.
2. A ">" icon in the calendar upper right is clicked.
3. A "<" icon in the calendar upper right is clicked.
4. There are no added events "Open Sesame".

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from left side your event did not disappear, and did not render after 1,2,3,4 manipulations.
Proposing that implementation of `render` method did that.
[Working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/am4yao?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Right away, I tried. But it didn't work.

ui-calendar, in bower, install, is the case different in circumstances?

I'm sorry, but please inform me about this part a little more conversantly.
>>Proposing that implementation of render method did that.